# Accessing code across different Modules in Android?

Tags: java, android, module

I have another module in my Android project ... 
[image of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKXQk.png)

Is it possible that I access some piece of code across the modules .. Like I have some `public static` methods in my `Utils class` in `app` module and I want to access in `library` module with out writing it again in library module.

Comment: https://www.leepoint.net/language/10basics/import.html

Answer (score 1):

That's not a good approach. Library module should be independent from base application code. If you make the library dependent from the application code you'll not be able to distribute the library indipendently from the app itself.
A better approach would be to move the code you need in the library module and call it from the application side.

Comment: But still if i want to access some thing in Library module or some piece of code across different modules .... so how it should be . ??